# Not able to understand the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to find two maximum salaries from every department in a table which had department no., salary, and various other columns. I got this answer; it surely works but I am not able to understand the logic.

```
select * 
from emp a where 2 > (select count( distinct(sal)) 
                      from emp 
                      where sal > a.sal and a.deptno=deptno)
order by deptno;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each row in employee, the query within the WHERE clause counts how many rows have a higher salary in the same department. The WHERE clause itself then restricts the results to only those salaries which have 1 or 0 rows (`2 >`) in the same department with a greater salary - i.e. the highest two salaries.

So with this data:

```
EmployeeId   Sal   DeptNo   No. of rows in the same department with higher salary
         1     1        1   3 (employees 2, 3 and 4)
         2     2        1   2 (employees 3 and 4)
         3     3        1   1 (employee 4)
         4     4        1   0
         5     1        2   2 (employees 6 and 7)
         6     2        2   1 (employee 7)
         7     3        2   0
```

...the query will select employees 3, 4, 6 and 7, as they're the employees with fewer than 2 employees who have a higher salary than them.

Comment: Ok i do not commit my response...pretty much similar !

Comment: One of those 'who was just who was quickest to the Answer button' questions :)

Comment: Thank you so very much sir....I was on this query for 3 hours....thanks a lot...ecen my tution sir could not explain me but you did it in a whim

Answer (score 2):

The inner select returns the number of higher salaries within the same department for a given employee. Now if there are less than two higher salaries within the same department then the given employee must be the top earning or next-to-top earning person within the department.

Answer (score 0):

Relocate the subquery to the `SELECT` clause without the 'top 2' restriction (will obviously get more rows back):

```
        select a.*, 
               (
                select count( distinct(sal)) 
                  from emp 
                 where sal > a.sal and a.deptno=deptno
               ) as tally
          from emp a
```

You can then restrict the resultset using a `WHERE` clause introducing a further level e.g.

```
select b.* 
  from (
        select a.*, 
               (
                select count( distinct(sal)) 
                  from emp 
                 where sal > a.sal and a.deptno=deptno
               ) as tally
          from emp a
       ) b     
 where b.tally < 2
 order 
    by b.deptno, b.tally;
```

The above is more verbose but maybe easier to follow the logic.

Comment: absolutely...just that you need to fire queries in two parts...by the way thanks